# Find the distance between greater than 100K locations

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, bigdata

I have two MySQL tables with locations, `table1` and `table2` (see below). There are > 100K rows in each table. I'd like to find the distance between every location in these two tables using their geolocations.

Here is the MySQL query to find the distance between a single geolocation, e.g, (-37.22, 88.88) and all the locations in `table1`.

```
$lat = -37.22;
$long = 88.88;

SELECT id, latitude, longitude, name
        ((2 * 3960 *
          ATAN2(
            SQRT(
              POWER(SIN((RADIANS($lat - latitude))/2), 2) +
              COS(RADIANS(latitude)) *
              COS(RADIANS($long)) *
              POWER(SIN((RADIANS($long - longitude))/2), 2)
            ),
            SQRT(1-(
              POWER(SIN((RADIANS($lat - latitude))/2), 2) +
              COS(RADIANS(latitude)) *
              COS(RADIANS($long)) *
              POWER(SIN((RADIANS($long - longitude))/2), 2)
            ))
          )
        )) AS distance FROM table1 ORDER BY distance;

Table1
id name latitude longitude
1   foo1    -37.12   62.34
2   foo2    -47.12   72.34
3   foo3    -57.12   82.34

Table2
id name latitude longitude
1   bar1    -38.22   66.11
2   bar2    -48.22   76.11
3   bar3    -58.22   86.11
```

Given that this is also a big data, I'm not sure where to start. Thoughts?

Comment: An important question is: What do you want to do with the distances?

Comment: Not sure if this will work but you could possibly look into an ETL solution like Pentaho Data Integration maybe ?

Comment: Are you asking for the distance between a single location and all table (1 and 2) locations, or for the distances between table 1 and table 2?

Comment: @mistermartin looks like it's the latter so 100kx100k = 10 Billion calculations.

Comment: Yes 10 billion calculations

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the "why?" is to help people at these locations find each other. Hopefully I presented generically though so it's more about the algorithms

Comment: @Maximus2012 I would be happy with a subset of 10B, I'm more interested in how one would go about this.

Comment: Consider defining 'finding' so you can simplify the problem. It is sometimes surprising what can be achieved this way. If you don't care just calculate all 10B distances.

Comment: Tim I wrote my answer before those new comment appears. What you are trying to create is a distance matrix, and is used in shortest route algorithm or TRSP.  If you want find near locations, that is a different issue and you can use spatial index to achive that without having a distance matrix.

Comment: A "spatial index" and a "distance matrix" naively sound like similar concepts to me. Can you explain the difference. If it is relevant, I could only get the top 100 shortest distances between each location so it could be reduced down to 10M calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want optimize travel or get near location you should go for spatial functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html
- But looks like you want every calculation so yes you will need do 10 billions operations.

  - I guess time isnt really a problem here. Because once you have it you can use it. And if new locations arrive just calculate distance against that location.
  - But you have to optimize. The most cost part of the query is calculate `SIN()` and `COS()` so create aditional field to each row with those value. So you have to do it only once and not 100k times for each row
  - Finally run a loop so you create the data in blocks.

**EDIT:**

After reading your last comment. You need a spatial index. The same way as you search one ID on your db, the spatial index will optimize your nearby search.

Also you can do box search. Instead of seach the whole universe you create a box around your point and search inside that box. Using normal float index you do something like this

```
  SELECT t1.name, t2.name,  mysql.Distancefunction(t1,t2) as distance
  from t1
  cross join t2
  WHERE t2.x between (t1.x - 0.001) and (t1.x + 0.001)   -- use x float index
    and t2.y between (t1.y - 0.001) and (t1.y + 0.001)   -- use y float index
    and mysql.Distancefunction(t1,t2) < 100 km           -- use spatial index
```

You can play with the delta 0.001. If you get too many results you use 0.0001. If you get few result you do a second step with 0.01 only for those locations without 100 neighbors.

Comment: Yes time isn't a problem. I'd like to be able to query the data once generated. Thanks for the suggestion to do `sin()` and `cos()` only once. Can you go into detail about the "loop" that "creates the data in blocks". Is it just simple `for` loop in whatever programming language mixed with `limit` `offset` in MySQL? I've never done large data and so I assume there are fancier solutions (not that I want to be fancy).

Comment: Depend on your needs and processing power. If you can do `select distance(*) from table1, table 2 where table1 between 1 and 10.000` in like one hour, then just copy / paste 10 times. Just dont run it all together or will be handle as a transaction and will be keeping temporal tables for the whole process.

Comment: If thing are slower and need do 100 query of 1000 each, then you may create a script to send the query